# Product Variant Affecting all Rows with Keyword in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update table inventories across two (`inventory`, `sold`) MySQL tables.

Let's say the sku we are dealing with is `BT888-16`

```
UPDATE inventory JOIN sold
ON inventory.sku = sold.sku
SET inventory.quantity = inventory.quantity - sold.quantity
```

This works as expected, but `BT888-16` is a product variant for the `BT888` sku.

How would I make it so that `BT888-16` in `sold` affects all quantity rows with `BT888` in `inventory`?

For example, `BT888-16` should affect all quantity rows with the phrase `BT888` in it?  `BT888` `BT888-01` `BT888-02` `BT888-03` -- all the way up to `BT888-***`

Comment: Join on the first 5 letters of the sku only, sum up the sold amounts grouping by the first 5 letters of the sku.

Comment: Yeah but not all SKUs have exactly 5 letters.  Was hoping there was a way to subtract any variation based off an exact match of the SKU.  Product variants all have a -*** attached to it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems kludgy, but you can put the logic in explicitly:

```
UPDATE inventory i JOIN
       sold s
       ON i.sku = s.sku or
          (s.sku = 'BT888-16' and i.sku like 'BT888-%')
    SET i.quantity = i.quantity - s.quantity;
```

EDIT:

I mean, you can start playing games like this:

```
UPDATE inventory i JOIN
       sold s
       ON i.sku = s.sku or
          (s.sku like '%-16' and i.sku like concat(substring_index(s.sku, '-', 1), '-%')
    SET i.quantity = i.quantity - s.quantity;
```

However, I think you need a column in a table that does the mapping for you.  That is, you need to be able to define groups of SKU ids that are "mutually" affected.

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know you could do that; incidentally, you forgot a bracket.

Comment: @jhaagsma, if you have edit privilege then please go on and edit the answer and I believe Gordon won't mind that at all

Comment: @Rahul Sorry, didn't realise I had edit privileges! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Interesting.  But this is going to require me to manually type in the SKU in everyone of my query?  This will become unmanagable.  Is it possible to do something like `like 'inventory.sku-%'` so I can do this programatically?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I will fiddle with this method, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!